# Cinnamon over Ubuntu known issues

Tags: ubuntu, cinnamon

I have been a long time Linux Mint user, and I *really* like Cinnamon. I know that Cinnamon can be installed over Ubuntu to replace Unity.

My question is this: if one were to do install Cinnamon over Ubuntu, does Cinnamon work the same as it does in a native Linux Mint installation? Are there any known issues that I should be aware of before doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cinnnamon it's officialy supported in ubuntu and has not more problem than any other Desktop enviroments:
http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=default&section=all&arch=any&keywords=cinnamon&searchon=names

Modify your question if you want to get an answer for an specific version of cinnamon and/or an specific version of ubuntu, and/or for a non oficial cinnamon installation source.